# Transforming data from columns to rows, select only if union of columns is not null using where clause to check for not null and != ''

Tags: sql

I need the select query to only select if the phone column is not null.

I have a phone record in a CRM that has the phone numbers in three columns. The ERP has a phone record with one column so it requires a record for each phone type: work, home cell. I want to import the records from the CRM to the ERP. The select statement for the insert query works but it inserts a record with an empty phone number when the phone number is null. I need it to only insert the record when the phone number is populated. An example of the query is listed below with test data in a subquery for the from statement.

SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Label,
    PHONE
FROM
    (SELECT 
         90864 AS ID, 'HOME' AS LABEL, '9185410013' AS PHONE
     UNION 
     SELECT 
         90864 AS ID, 'WORK' AS LABEL, '' AS PHONE
     UNION 
     SELECT 
         90864 AS ID, 'CELL' AS LABEL, '' AS PHONE
    ) AS Test_Data
```

Comment: Add a where clause? Like this. Where PHONE > '' This would filter out NULL and empty string at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explicit version (update, added some null values just to show it works there per description)

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Label,
    PHONE
FROM
(        
SELECT 90864 AS ID, 'HOME' AS LABEL, '9185410013' AS PHONE
UNION 
SELECT 90864 AS ID, 'WORK' AS LABEL, '' AS PHONE
UNION 
SELECT 90864 AS ID, 'CELL' AS LABEL, '' AS PHONE
UNION
SELECT 90865 AS ID, 'HOME' AS LABEL, '9185410013' AS PHONE
UNION 
SELECT 90865 AS ID, 'WORK' AS LABEL, null AS PHONE
UNION 
SELECT 90865 AS ID, 'CELL' AS LABEL, null AS PHONE
) as Test_Data
WHERE PHONE is not null AND PHONE != ''
```

Results:

```
ID  Label   PHONE
90864   HOME    9185410013
90865   HOME    9185410013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Label,
    PHONE
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATALENGTH(PHONE) > 0
```

Comment: That works but is nonSARGable. If this is a small dataset probably not a big deal but you don't need a function here.